# Get HTML of another page in another domain using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Right now, I am using curl in PHP to get the HTML source code of some remote web page.

Is there any way I can get the same HTML source code of some cross-domain web page in JavaScript? Any tutorials?

Comment: Not without the cooperation of the target site.

Comment: Or without the use of some intermediary that can proxy the target site.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to know about [JSONP](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jsonp) to access cross-domain web pages in js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonp?sort=votes

Comment: JSONP is now mostly obsolete, since [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is supported in many browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Q.  How is this any different than issuing an AJAX "GET http://otherdomain.com/page.html" call?

A.  The same-origin policy checks the HTTP response headers for AJAX requests to remote domains, and if they don't contain a suitable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the request fails.

So, there are two ways to make this work:

- If you control the other domain, you can include the following header in the HTTP response:

  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
  (details at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control))
- If you don't, you're stuck implementing a server-side proxy (for example, [this simple PHP proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/proxy/php_proxy_simple.txt)).

In any case, once you implement one of the two options above, you're left with a simple AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mydomain.com/path/to/proxy.php?url="+
        encodeURI("http://otherdomain.com/page.html"),
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(result) {
    $("#result").text(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: The cross-domain restriction is a restriction on the javascript.  Your html code can have img, script, and link tags that GET data from any domain.  However, generally speaking, javascript code cannot issue a GET to another domain.  I say "generally speaking" because there are some workarounds, such as Flash, server-side proxy, CORS, etc.

Comment: I tried your example and it worked for same domain url on which this script was hosted. But when i tried for different urls it gave me an error as below : 
`GET http://www.somedomain.com/index.php undefined (undefined)` 
i also got following error once when tried for few domain urls:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.otherdomain.com/index.php. Origin http://www.mydomain.com/index.php is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`
kindly help!!

Answer (score 0):

This solution I just found might be of use like the other workarounds...

http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/